# Equality of Sigma Algebras Generated by Carathéodory's Extension Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

We define a set $E \subseteq X $ as **measurable** if
$$l(A)=l(E \cap A)+l(E^{c} \cap A)$$
for every $A \subseteq X $, where $l$ is an outer measure. Suppose now we have two measures $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ such that for every $E \subseteq X$
$$\mu_{1}(E)=0 \iff \mu_{2}(E)=0$$
Does this imply that the two sigma algebras of measurable sets related to the measures above by Carathéodory's Extension Theorem are equal?